# How can I add custom fields to WordPress's built-in taxonomy meta boxes?

Tags: php, wordpress

Specifically, I want to add a couple fields to the Categories meta box ('categorydiv'). I was hoping there would be a filter, but I couldn't find one. I know I can create a custom meta box, but it will be easiest for my client if they see these fields tied to choosing a category. The visual break of a new meta box is undesirable, and it would be unacceptable to have it appear anywhere but immediately below Categories (e.g., under Tags).

Answer (score 1):

There is no action/filter hook to customize the output of WP's taxonomy meta boxes. There are two options: replace the Categories meta box with a custom version, or move your meta fields into the Categories meta box with JavaScript.

I added my custom meta boxes to the Categories div in 5 minutes with jQuery. I prefer this version because it's short, simple, and in most cases more versatile.

Do [`add_meta_boxes` as normal](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), then add another function to jQuery it up:

```
function my_meta_box_customization() {
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($) {
            $(function(){
                $('#my-meta-box-div-id').find('.inside').appendTo('#categorydiv')
                    .end().end().remove();
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_meta_box_customization' );
```

I like to throw a `<style>` tag in there, too.

I'm not going to bother with all the code for replacing the Categories meta box entirely, but the general idea would be:

1. [`remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'post', 'side' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)
2. `add_meta_boxes` with a function that loads [`post_categories_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_categories_meta_box/) into a variable and customizes it with regex or some such.
3. Mess around with adding, removing and re-adding meta boxes to get the desired order (e.g, Categories under Publish, above Tags).

It would be a hassle, and I'm not recommending it.

Comment: If anyone has other suggestions, I'd love to hear them!